# Getting syntax error when trying to install googlemaps module in python via pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to install the Google maps module in python but I am getting a syntax error. Below is the error message. Please help.

```
(gmapenv) C:\Python\Virtual Environment\gmapenv\Scripts>pip install GoogleMaps
Downloading/unpacking GoogleMaps
  Running setup.py egg_info for package GoogleMaps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "C:\Python\Virtual Environment\gmapenv\build\GoogleMaps\setup.py", li
ne 18, in <module>
        import googlemaps
      File "googlemaps\googlemaps.py", line 471
        print main.__doc__
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "C:\Python\Virtual Environment\gmapenv\build\GoogleMaps\setup.py", line 1
8, in <module>

    import googlemaps

  File "googlemaps\googlemaps.py", line 471

    print main.__doc__

             ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Python\Virtual E
nvironment\gmapenv\build\GoogleMaps
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Vimal\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: Should it be import GoogleMaps instead of import googlemaps

Comment: python 2 and 3 are not compatible

Comment: @heinst Thank you for answering. I never used the import statement. I was trying to install the googlemaps module and got the error message

Comment: If you're in python 3, and you try in use a module meant for python 2, bad things will often happen. In the case, the module uses the old style python 2 ``print value`` statement instead of the python 3 ``print(value)`` function. Hence why you get a syntax error.

Comment: @user3777324 so you figured it out?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers guys. Yes it is the version problem. Earlier I tried python Version 3.3.2 now I installed version 2.7 and it worked well. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you tried to run python2 code using python3. Try reinstalling python : https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/